# Is it possible to edit a symlink with a text editor?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, symlink

When we create a symlink, the number of bytes the symlink takes up is exactly the length of the origin it points to. For instance,

```
$ ln -s dest link1
$ ln -s longer_dest link2
$ ls -l
lrwxrwxrwx 1 username  4 Mar 26 20:21 link1 -> dest
lrwxrwxrwx 1 username 11 Mar 26 20:21 link2 -> longer_dest
```

where `link1` takes up 4 bytes, which is the length of `dest`; `link2` takes up 11 bytes, which is the length of `longer_dest`. Therefore, symlinks are in fact no more than the destination path stored in plain text. So I am wondering **if it is possible to edit (the destination) of a symlink in text editors**, preferably Emacs. I googled for a while and couldn't find anyone talking about this. Note that this question is purely out of curiosity; **I know full well that I can overwrite a symlink by `ln -f -s`**.

Comment: **For those who voted close**, I believe this is a valid, clearly stated question; and although it is not directly programming-related, it is of interest to programmers, plus there are a ton of this kind of questions here—just look at related questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, in Emacs this is possible in dired-mode, specifically wdired (writable dired) mode.

Note, dired and wdired both are built-in packages.

Here's an example...

[image: wdired editing a symlink]

(BTW: I'm using [Smex](https://github.com/nonsequitur/smex) to give Emacs [`M-x`](https://kb.iu.edu/d/acqm) command search & execute a more ergonomic UI + fuzzy matching)

Comment: Text version of how to do this: once in dired, `C-x C-q` to enter the wdired mode. Make the desired changes in the dired buffer. Then `C-c C-c` to apply the changes.

Comment: BTW since `S-w` is unbound (shift w) I use that in the `dired-mode-map` for starting `wdired-change-to-wdired-mode`.  `C-x C-s` also saves changes made in `wdired-mode` which is easier on your muscle memory.

Answer (score 6):

It's possible in principle, but the editor would need to specifically support it, since reading the destination of a symlink requires a special system call: `readlink()`.

You're unlikely to find any editors that actually do this, since it's not very useful, and conflicts with what most users want the editor to do when asked to open a symlink:  open the file that it points to.

Comment: Thanks, this sounds reasonable. I voted up but won't accept just yet.

Answer (score 2):

As per the *Storage of symbolic links* section in Wikipedia's article [Symbolic Links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link), the symlinks are stored in an **inode**.  This inode is a data structure containing several information about the file in question - as per [this thread](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-security-4/can-we-change-entries-in-the-inode-table-of-a-file-linux-881578/), the `touch` command can be used to change some of its values.  So, it may not be possible to modify it by using a text editor, due to the problems that @Wyzard mentioned, but it might be modifiable by using some other command-line tools like `touch`.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible directly, as others have already pointed out, but of course you can write a script for it. Here's one I came up with when I had to change lots of symlinks

```
#! /bin/bash

tmp=$(mktemp)
trap "rm $tmp" EXIT

while [ ! -z "$1" ]; do
    filename="$1"; shift
    if [ ! -h "$filename" ]; then
        echo "Not a symlink: $filename";
        continue
    fi
    stat -c "%N" "$filename" >> $tmp
done
emacs $tmp

while read filename linkname; do
    ln -sf "$linkname" "$filename"
done < <(sed "s/'\(.*\)' -> '\(.*\)'/\1 \2/" $tmp)
```

It worked for me, but it's certainly not perfect, so use at your own risk...